# Disabling a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jQuery function which monitors the 'beforeunload' status.
So therefore every time i do a refresh this method is executed.

```
The function is as follows:


 <script type="text/javascript"> 

var bIsSafeRedirect = false; 

$('#reload').click(function() 
{ 
bIsSafeRedirect = true; 
location.reload(); 

}); 

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() 
{ 
if (!bIsSafeRedirect ) 
{ 
return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here'; 
} 
}); 



</script>
```

Now i have other components such as

```
<td onClick="window.location.replace('try.html')" id="reload" target="Content">
```

which onclick reloads the same page.
I this scenario where the table data is clicked i dont want the jQuery function to be invoked.I want it to be skipped as a special case.
How can i achieve it.

The entire code is shown below

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Refresh a page in jQuery</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function load() 
{ 
document.getElementById("first").value="hello"; 
} 
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 

<h1>Stop a page from exit with jQuery</h1> 

<button id="reload">Refresh a Page in jQuery</button> 

 <script type="text/javascript"> 

var bIsSafeRedirect = false; 

function unload(type, url){ 
if(type === 'noReturn'){ 
$(window).unbind("beforeunload"); 
window.location.replace(url); 
} else if(!bIsSafeRedirect && type === 'return') { 
var conf = confirm('do you want to quit'); 
if(conf){ 
alert("ajax"); 
} else { 
return false; 
} 
} 
}  

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){ 
unload('return'); 
}); 



</script> 

<table> 
<tr>
<td onClick="window.location.replace('try.html')" id="reload" target="Content"> 
<td onClick="unload('noReturn','try.html')">
Usual Refresh 
</td>
</tr> 
</table> 
<input type="text" id="first" size="15"/> 
<input type="button" onclick="load()" value="load"/> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<td onClick="replaceContent();" id="reload" target="Content">
```

Here is the `replaceContent()` function:

```
function replaceContent(){
  $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
  window.location.replace('try.html');
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly.How can i get the status whether the user has clicked ok or cancel when my custom message appears.I wanted to fire an ajax request based on the user's choice.

Comment: You can use the return value of `confirm` function. `status = confirm('Are you sure you want to leave?')`

Answer (score 2):

one way is to prepend this to `onClick`:

```
$(window).unbind('beforenload');
```

the other way is to use a global flag, exactly like the `bIsSafeRedirect` you're currently using. Change the `beforeunload` handler body like this:

```
if (shouldRefresh && !bIsSafeRedirect) 
{ 
    return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here'; 
}
```

and set `shouldRefresh` value to `false` in `onClick`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a function that handles both of these:

```
function unload(type, url){
    if(type === 'noReturn'){
        $(window).unbind("beforeunload");
        window.location.replace(url);
    } else if(!bIsSafeRedirect && type === 'return') {
        var conf = confirm('Confirmation message');
        if(conf){
            // fire ajax call here
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then fire this function in your `bind()` call:

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){
    unload('return');
});
```

Since we supply the `return` string to the `type` parameter, it fires the `else if` part of the if statement, which doesn't unbind the `beforeunload` event and so returns that string.

And for your other components:

```
<td onClick="unload('noReturn','try.html')"></td>
```

So now, since we have supplied the `noReturn` string to the `type` parameter, the first part of the if statement will execute and load the page without the interference of the `beforeunload` handler by unbinding it.

With this method, you can use the `unload` function on multiple elements' inline `onclick` handlers and make it a more globally usable script.

Comment: This works perfectly.How can i get the status whether the user has clicked ok or cancel when my custom message appears.I wanted to fire an ajax request based on the user's choice.

Comment: @gautamvegeta: I edited my answer. What happens now is a dialog box appears (a confirmation dialog, to be exact). If the user clicks OK, the first portion of the inner if statement is fired, where you would put your ajax call. If not, it'll return `false`.

Comment: I have added the entire code.There seems to be a problem in the page closing.The message is getting called twice and web page is not closing too.

Comment: And the message is getting displayed for refresh and the close buttons.How can this be separated.

Comment: @gautamvegeta: I cannot do all the work for you. I've showed you the concept here, so wrap your head around it, figure out how it works, and you should be able to find out how to fix your problems. Do some Google searches.